# Trouble accessing the methods of a duplicated class

Tags: c++

I'm trying to access the method `a()` in `Foo` by creating a new object from `Foo` and calling its `duplicate` method (`duplicate` creates a new Foo object). Then I call `::a()` since I should have access to the class. But it's not working. Can anyone explain why?

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

class Foo {
    public:
        int a() { return 5; }

        Foo *duplicate() {
            return new Foo();
        }
};

int main() {

    Foo foo;

    Foo *a = foo.duplicate()::a(); // should return 5

    cout << a;

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must use the `->` operator to access members of object pointers. So try this:

```
foo.duplicate()->a();
```

And you cant assign 5 (an integer as returned by the `Foo::a()` method) to `Foo *a`, why are you trying to do that?

Comment: To answer your question, I'm trying to duplicate the class in order to get its `a` method. I'm trying to `cout` 5 from it. It's just practice

Comment: "To get its `a` method", you mean like a function pointer? Or do you mean the value that method returns?

Comment: First I do this: `Foo *a = foo.duplicate();` then I do this: `cout << a->a();`. To get its `a` method; that's what I mean.

Comment: Technically, you are **invoking** its method.